# Updating Content Provider

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create an VSCode Extension that parses a JSON file from a Web Service and returns the result within VSCode using the [Content Provider](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#TextDocumentContentProvider)

I initually show static data while the data is being retrieved and parsed.

[image]

In the mean time I retrieve the data.
[image]

But how do I update the contentprovider content?

[extension.js file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AitPFpVZnMk6rdwenjgVn8vQwdtVBA)

Comment: Solved the issue myself. Check https://github.com/stefanstranger/vscode-psconfeu2017/blob/master/extensions for more info.

Comment: Do you still have this repository online? I would be interested in taking a look. I am creating a similar extension myself.